# Why does a Poisson process hurt the prerequesites of the Kolmogorov-Chentsov theorem

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, continuity, holder-spaces, poisson-process

I have a question for you.
Obviously, by looking at the sample paths of a Poisson process with parameter $\lambda >0$, this process does not have a hölder-continuous version.

But why? I have the feeling that the conditions for the Kolmogorov-Chentsov theorem are not hurt. This is part of my homework and it puzzles me the whole weekend already.

A simple version of that theorem states:

" Let $X_t$ be a real-valued process. For every $T >0$ there exists $\alpha, \beta, C > 0$ with

$E[|X_t - X_s|^\alpha] \leq C|t - s|^{1 + \beta}$ on $[0,T]$

Then there exists a version of $X_t$ with hölder-continuous paths."

Assuming $t > s$ and $\alpha \geq 1$, we can use Jensen and find

$E[|X_t - X_s|^\alpha] \geq \lambda^\alpha (t - s)^\alpha$

which goes to zero, so the conditions are fulfilled (?). For $\alpha < 1$, I could calculate the fractional moments of the Poisson distribution via fractional Bell polynomials - but those are even negative, depending on $\lambda$ and $\alpha$. 
So they could be fulfilling the prerequisites for a given $\beta$ as well.

Where am I wrong? I have to be somewhere, but I don't find out where.

Comment: Why do you think tthat the condition is satisfied if $\mathbb{E}(|X_t-X_s|^{\alpha}) \geq \lambda^{\alpha} (t-s)^{\alpha}$...? Kolmgorov-Chenstov requires an upper bound; not a lower bound.

Comment: Yes, but then I can write $λ^\alpha (t−s)^\alpha \leq C |t - s|^{1+\beta}$, which is feasible for given $C, \alpha, \beta$!

Comment: So....? To put it in an abstract way: You proved $a \geq b$; we know that $b \leq c$... but this does, in general, not imply $a \leq c$.

Comment: Nono, look again, it's $a \leq b$ in my case.

Comment: We have $\mathbb{E}(|X_t-X_s|^{\alpha}) \color{red}{\geq} \lambda^{\alpha} (t-s)^{\alpha} \color{\red}{\leq} C |t-s|^{1+\beta}$. So how do you conclude $\mathbb{E}(|X_t-X_s|^{\alpha}) \leq C |t-s|^{1+\beta}$ from this chain of inequalities?

Comment: Ah, now I see what you mean. I wanted to construct a contradiction, assuming the inequality is given, show that the expected value has a lower bound greater than zero.

Edit: And even if - Take $\alpha = 1, \beta > 0, C = \lambda > 0$. then the inequality is fulfilled and KCT just asks for existence of these numbers. What am I doing wrong? Edit 2: Oh wait, it's not, since $|t - s| \rightarrow 0$. Okay. But how do I conclude the rest?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since the Poisson process has stationary increments, i.e.

$$\mathbb{E}(|X_t-X_s|^{\alpha}) = \mathbb{E}(|X_{|t-s|}|^{\alpha}), \qquad s,t \geq 0,$$

it suffices to consider the case $s=0$. By definition $X_t$ is Poisson distributed with parameter $\lambda t$, and therefore

$$\mathbb{E}(|X_t|^{\alpha}) \geq \mathbb{E}(1 \cdot 1_{\{X_t=1\}}) = \mathbb{P}(X_t = 1) = e^{-\lambda t} (\lambda t).$$

This gives

$$\frac{1}{t} \mathbb{E}(|X_t|^{\alpha}) \geq e^{-\lambda t} \lambda \xrightarrow[]{t \to 0} \lambda.$$

Hence,

$$0 < c:= \inf_{t \in (0,1]} \frac{1}{t} \mathbb{E}(|X_t|^{\alpha})$$

which in turn implies

$$\mathbb{E}(|X_t|^{\alpha}) = t \left( \frac{1}{t} \mathbb{E}(|X_t|^{\alpha}) \right) \geq c t$$

for small $t$. In particular, this shows that an estimate of the form $\mathbb{E}(|X_t|^{\alpha}) \leq C t^{1+\beta}$ cannot hold for any $\beta>0$.

Comment: Thank you! I just had that idea when I wrote my last comment (that for $\alpha = 1$ there exists no $\beta > 0$). Appreciated!

Comment: @DanielBischof You are welcome.